# Pandas Python Visualization - ValueError: shape mismatch: ERROR

Tags: python, pandas, mat

*Edit:
Why the right plot (Bar) is showing 50% , half black screen on the plot, wierd numbers, "garbage"... how to fix the right plot ?

here is my code:

```
top_series = all_data.head(50).groupby('Top Rated ')['Top Rated '].count()
top_values = top_series.values.tolist()
top_index = ['Top Rated', 'Not Top Rated']
top_colors = ['#27AE60', '#E74C3C']


rating_series = all_data.head(50).groupby('Rating')['Rating'].count()
rating_values = rating_series.values.tolist()
rating_index = ['High' , 'Low']
rating_colors = ['#F1C40F', '#27AE60']

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(16,5))
axs[0].pie(top_values, labels=top_index, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90,
           explode=(0.05, 0.05), radius=1.5, colors=top_colors, textprops={'fontsize':15})
    
axs[1].bar(rating_series.index, rating_series.values, color='b')
axs[1].set_xlabel('Rating')
axs[1].set_ylabel('Amount')


fig.suptitle('Does "Rating" really affect on Top Sellers ? ')
```

CSV cols:
[image]

Output (look at the right plot):

[image]

Comment: Where is the `rating_values` defined?

Comment: @DanielWlazło Yeah sorry just edit now, but still same ERROR: 'ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape'

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, that `keys` is a list of all keys. So it can have a different shape than the `top_values`.
If you would do:

```
axs[1].bar(top_series.index, top_series.values, color='b')
```

It should work well.

But, if you just want to plot the histogram, there is even shorter version, without temporary objects:

```
all_data['Top Rated '].value_counts().plot(kind = 'bar', ax=axs[1])
```

Edit: The `Rating` column is a numeric one, not a string one. You have to create a column which will have values `High` and `Low`. For example:

```
all_data['Rating_Cat'] = all_data['Rating'].apply(lambda x : 'High' if (x > 10000000 ) else 'Low')
```

And then use this column to plot this kind of bar plot

Comment: unfortunally its works 50%... i tried to apply it on another col in the csv, that the left plot (pie) will be "Top Col" , the right plot (bar), but i dont know why its show alots go numbers, and black screen, something wierd.. im editing to the full bloack code if you can have a look please. *Edit

Comment: Can you please add some sample data? Because it's a simple bar plot and I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: Hey yes, just uploaded the output. look

Comment: The `Rating` column is a numeric one, not a string one. You have to create a column which will have values `High` and `Low`. For example:

`all_data['Rating_Cat'] = all_data['Rating'].apply(lambda x : 'High' if (x > 10000000 ) else 'Low')`

And then use this column to plot this kind of bar plot. Now it plots all of the values that you have in `Rating` column.

Comment: Hey thanks alots!! may i send you maybe another issue ? mail / discord ?

Comment: Ask on stack - it might be useful for others.